# Spectral gaps and convergence of solutions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-gap

I'm reading the following [paper](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/07/P01.MV-FPReview.pdf) by C. Villani on the Fokker-Planck equation $$u_t = Lu$$  with $L = \Delta - \nabla V\cdot \nabla$ in which he states (pg. 3) that the existence of a spectral gap for the nonnegative self-adjoint operator $L$ implies exponential convergence of solutions to the stationary solution $e^{-V},$ and that this follows by 'elementary spectral analysis.' What little I know of spectral methods does not allow me to see this, and I cannot find an explicit theorem that would be relevant. How can this be shown easily, say assuming Stone's theorem and/or the spectral theorem?

Comment: They are in a situation where 0 is an isolated eigenvalue (with only one eigenfunction) and the rest of the spectrum is in $]-\infty, -\delta]$ with $\delta>0$. In this situation, $e^{tL}$ fix the zero eigenfunctions and converges exponentially to zero (as $e^{-\delta t}$) on the orthogonal complement.